# I need to process a corpus consisting of over 300,000 words in Python. Is there a distributed environment that I can consider?

Tags: python

```
pattern = r'[A-Z][A-Z]+'
corpus_copy = corpus.split()
corrected_corpus = ''

for term in corrected_corpus:
        if (len(re.findall(pattern, term)) == 0 and wordnet.synsets(term) != ''):
                corrected_corpus += spell(term)+" "
```

This takes forever for execution, and eventually breaks the loop. I know this is a rudimentary way of traversing through it. What are few recommended distributed systems that are fast and efficient that I can try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator functions may solve your problem.To know more about application of Generators in text files See section 5.3.1 from this link http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Comment: Thank you. What is your opinion on the multiprocessing package in Python?

Comment: You can do multiprocessing + generator + lazy evaluation with `Pool.imap`. Works well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd want a more durable and general solution for larger problems I'd recommend something along the lines of [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

There's also other alternatives such as [RQ](http://python-rq.org/) (which is simpler than Celery).